# Create a point in a direction In Cesiumjs

Tags: math, matrix, quaternions, cesiumjs, euler-angles

I am using CesiumJs. I would like to create point D at distance C from point A using the direction B

```
Point A => start Position (CartographicPosition {latitude, longitude; altitude})
Direction B => direction from A (HeadingPitchRoll {heading, pitch, roll})
Distance C => in meters
```

I am trying to get the rotation an object is facing, and create a point in front of him.

My current implementation is

```
  public createROIfromRotation(position: Cartographic, rotation: HeadingPitchRoll): Cartographic {

    const pos = Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84.cartographicToCartesian(position);
    const quat = Cesium.Transforms.headingPitchRollQuaternion(pos, rotation);
    const rot = CesiumMath.QuaternionToEuler(quat);

    const dir = Cesium.Cartesian3.multiplyByScalar(rot, 10, new Cesium.Cartesian3());
    const roiPos = Cesium.Cartesian3.add(pos, dir, new Cesium.Cartesian3());


    return Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84.cartesianToCartographic(roiPos);
  }
```

But it is not rotating around the object, it is doing some kind of curve in different planes.

I would like the red point to be always in front of the truck at 10 meters distance
[Exemple](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/#c=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)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed using

```
  public createROIfromRotation(position: Cartographic, rotation: HeadingPitchRoll) {
    const cartesianPosition = Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84.cartographicToCartesian(position);

    rotation.heading = rotation.heading - CesiumMath.deg2Rad(90);
    const referenceFrame1 = Cesium.Transforms.headingPitchRollQuaternion(cartesianPosition, rotation);

    const rotationMatrix = Cesium.Matrix3.fromQuaternion(referenceFrame1, new Cesium.Matrix3());

    // Replace 1000 for changing the distance
    const rotationScaled = Cesium.Matrix3.multiplyByVector(rotationMatrix, new Cesium.Cartesian3(10000, 0, 0), new Cesium.Cartesian3());
    const roiPos = Cesium.Cartesian3.add(cartesianPosition, rotationScaled, new Cesium.Cartesian3());

    this.store$.dispatch(new ROIsStoreActions.CreateROIPoint({position: Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84.cartesianToCartographic(roiPos), id: uuid()}));
  }
```

So basically, converting everything to Matrix3 before applying my calculations